# How do I correct query a friends table for user and friend data without distinct, or union

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have a table called friends and a table photos. I'm trying to query friends photos OR the users who has the friends photos. I think I need to alias an inner join on the friends table but not sure

```
Friends Table
user_id int
friend_id int 
[other attribute field]

Photos Table
id      int
user_id int
[other attribute field]
```

For example if I want to query friends photos i'd run

```
SELECT `photos`.`id` FROM `photos` LEFT JOIN `friends` ON (`friends`.`friend_id` = `photos`.`user_id`) WHERE `friends`.`user_id` = 1
```

Or if I wanted to query just the users table id do

```
SELECT `photos`.`id` FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`user_id` = 1
```

The problem is when I try to get both in the same result set like

```
SELECT  `photos`.`id` 
FROM  `photos` 
LEFT JOIN  `friends` ON (  `friends`.`friend_id` =  `photos`.`user_id` ) 
WHERE  `friends`.`user_id` =1
OR  `photos`.`user_id` =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Which obviously gets the wrong results because of the left join I get a result for every friend I have

I'm thinking I need to inner join an aliased table for the OR clause or something but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if just use UNION for two your first queries:

```
SELECT `photos`.`id` 
   FROM `photos` 
        LEFT JOIN `friends` ON (`friends`.`friend_id` = `photos`.`user_id`) 
   WHERE `friends`.`user_id` = 1
union all 
SELECT `photos`.`id` FROM `photos` WHERE `photos`.`user_id` = 1
```

If you do not want to use UNION then

```
SELECT `photos`.`id` 
   FROM `photos` where `photos`.`user_id`=1
                   or `photos`.`user_id` 
                       in (select `friends`.`friend_id` from `friends`
                                             where `friends`.`user_id` = 1)
```

Comment: I've added a query without `UNION`

Answer (score 1):

I think union is the best approach for this problem.

or you can try to use a subquery with 'OR'

```
SELECT photos.id FROM photos WHERE 
(photos.user_id = 1) or 
(photos.user_id in (select friends.friend_id from friends where friends.user_id=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you have shown, you don't need the `JOIN` at all.  Since the `photos` table already contains the user ids, the `friends` table isn't needed for anything in what you have shown.  Just query `photos` directly to get the photos of particular users.

Maybe you really want something different, such as only returning a photo if someone actually is a friend.  In that case, you need `inner join` rather than left join, and you can do it like this:

```
SELECT  `photos`.`id` 
FROM  `photos` 
INNER JOIN  `friends` ON
  `friends`.`friend_id` =  `photos`.`user_id`  AND
  `friends`.`user_id` =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

If you want to return the photos of friend with ID 1, and also the photos of user ID 2 whether that person is a friend or not, do something like this:

```
SELECT  `photos`.`id` 
FROM  `photos` 
LEFT JOIN  `friends` ON
  `friends`.`friend_id` =  `photos`.`user_id`  AND
  `friends`.`user_id` = 1
WHERE
  `friends`.`friend_id` IS NOT NULL OR
  `photos`.`user_id` = 2
LIMIT 0 , 30
```